# photoshop script(photoshop file opening in the background)

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I need to edit the text layer of psd files and save them in jpg or png format using C#.

The problem I'm facing is without opening Photoshop in the background its not happening. Here is a code example.

```
string adobejavascriptfilepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    , "Scripts\\AdobeScript.jsx"
);

var cArray = aArguments.Cast<object>().ToArray();
//launching photoshop
app.DoJavaScriptFile(adobejavascriptfilepath, cArray, 1);
```

Here I'm calling the javascript file and modifying the text layers of psd files.

Comment: you mean foreground ,and not background right ?